# Expected number of vertices of a "random" polytope in $d$ dimensions

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a polytope with $m$ hyperfaces in $d$ dimensions. How many vertices should I expect it to have?

Clearly an upper bound is $\binom{m}{d}$ if every face touches every other, as in the simplex, but for $m > d+1$ this situation is overly pessimistic.

I found a paper by Matheiss and Rubin (https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/MISC/BIBLIOTECA/trunk/Matheiss.pdf) which gives an upper bound $O(m^{d/2})$ of vertices. But again, this is in the worst case. How many vertices should one expect?

I imagine this will depend somewhat on how one defines a "typical" polytope. I'm not sure myself, but one setup would be sampling points from a normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}^d$ until their convex hull has $m$ faces.

Comment: For the convex hull construction, every face would be simplicial except for rare exceptions with probability zero. That's because it is almost never the case that more than $d$ random points are coplanar. I don't have a good estimate yet about how many faces to expect at each vertex.